# Amavisd-new cannot start - missing Unix::Syslog (CentOS)

Tags: centos, email, perl, syslog, amavis

I followed the basic instructions here for installing amavisd, spamassassin + 
clamav...

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Amavisd

I get the following error when trying to start amavisd...

```
# service amavisd start
Starting Mail Virus Scanner (amavisd): ERROR: MISSING REQUIRED BASIC MODULES:
  Unix::Syslog
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/amavisd line 237.
                                                       [FAILED]
```

However the perl unix syslog already appears to be installed...

```
# yum install perl-Unix-Syslog.i386
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
amzn-main                                                                         | 2.1 kB      00:00
amzn-updates                                                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
1539 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Package perl-Unix-Syslog-1.1-1.el5.rf.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any help /pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well this is all new to me. How to install the perl syslog module...

1) Install Perl CPAN (if not already installed)

```
# yum install cpan
```

2) Drop into the Perl shell

```
# perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

3) Now at the cpan prompt, install Unix:Syslog

```
cpan[1]> install Unix::Syslog
```

I now have a further error to sort out, but this is for another thread...

```
# service amavisd start
Starting Mail Virus Scanner (amavisd): Problem in Amavis::DB or Amavis::DB::SNMP code: Can't locate BerkeleyDB.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at (eval 82) line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 82) line 19.
```